# where should i change data according to API response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using redux

Whenever i get the data i'm gonna define an if statement which changes data as for showing them on the screen

consider following code as API response

```
API_RESPONSE:{
  status:3
}
```

then at the code i want to show different values according to response

```
if(API_RESPONSE.status === 3){
  return <div>cancel</div>
  }
```

my question is where should i do the `if` statement,

at `redux action` or at the code where i'm trying to get them from reducer

Comment: You can simply do conditional rendering within you jsx. You can read more on this here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/5-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-64730323b434

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to check where you're trying to show UI, because if you check in `reducer` and for example set a value for it, you need to check it again in the UI to see what you should show

Answer (score 1):

After getting a response from API and storing the response in the redux state you need to get that state in your component where you want to show the UI. So the answer to your question is that you have to do the conditional rendering in the component after getting the data from the redux state

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `reducer` for handling this state, you could store in it.

But i think it's okay to `setState` or change the `props` in your corresponding component.